# How to replace a text with underscore using sfk filter command

Tags: batch-file

I have got a temporary file that my script creates and it has got the following path within it

Test_Path =D:\test\

I have got this command within my script which should delete "Test_Path =" and should just leave D:\test\ in the temp file

sfk filter test1.tmp -rep "_ Test_Path =_ _"

but this is not working as "_" is a already a delimiter in this command and my string has also got an underscore in it "Test_Path"

How could i possibly do this? My updated file should just have the path D:\test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the only string in the file:

```
set /p string= < file.txt
echo %string:~11% > file.txt
```

It will write file contents (the first line) to the variable `string`, then remove first 11 characters (which is `Test_Path=`) from the variable value and write it back to the file.

Comment: I'm expressing my gratitude for your appreciation, and suggesting to consider accepting the answer if it succeeded :)

Comment: Thanks Elvin, Since you look to be a genius in batch scripting may i please ask you another question

Query:  
---------

Comment: Yes, you can ask on chat or post it as another question and mention me for notification.

Comment: Thanks Elvin, i figured it out !! I will mention you in my future queries :)